# How to display data with multiple space in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

In my application SlickGrid is used for display data in tabular format. If any data contains multiple spaces, it is displayed with single space in Grid. I need to display the data as it was originally (i.e.- with multiple spaces). To overcome this problem I added one additional attribute in slick-cell class and it is white-space: pre-wrap;. After this modification data is displayed in FireFox browser correctly (i.e.- with multiple spaces), but in IE(8), data is displayed with single space. 
One point want to mention that we have some screens where Ajax call (JSON response) use to populate SlickGrid. In this scenario data is displayed with multiple spaces (as it is) in IE.

My concern am I missing something?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @kiwi1342 : I have trying to prepare one sample in jsfiddle. But in IE8 it is not opening properly. So I couldn't find the result of the sample code in IE8. Please find my jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/avishek010687/yakfr476/

Answer (score 0):

you should write your own cell formatter, that will replace spaces with not-braking spaces. something like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uof2m0qp/

```
function nbspFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDefs, dataContext){
    return value.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;");
}
```